# Counting duplicate records between two dates in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I'm trying to COUNT the number of duplicate records between two dates.

Here is some data.

| rec_date | name | med | directions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-22 | mr blogs | paracetamol | ONE tablet FOUR times a day |
| 2022-06-21 | mr blogs | paracetamol | ONE tablet FOUR times a day |
| 2022-06-20 | mr blogs | aspirin | ONE tablet FOUR times a day |
| 2022-04-19 | mr blogs | iron | ONE tablet ONCE a day |
| 2022-03-09 | mr blogs | salbutamol | ONE puff when required |
| 2022-02-08 | mr blogs | paracetamol | TWO tablets FOUR times a day |
| 2022-02-06 | mr blogs | paracetamol | TWO tablets FOUR times a day |
| 2022-02-04 | mr blogs | paracetamol | ONE tablet FOUR times a day |

So far, I've managed to work this out; this counts how many times an exact match is duplicated.

```
SELECT
rec_date,
name,
med,
directions
COUNT(*) as number

FROM
datatable da

WHERE
da.rec_date>={d '2022-06-20'}
AND da.rec_date<={d '2022-06-22'}
GROUP BY med, name
HAVING COUNT(*)>2
```

This would result 1 duplicate as these are the same.

| rec_date | name | med | directions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-22 | mr blogs | paracetamol | ONE tablet FOUR times a day |
| 2022-06-21 | mr blogs | paracetamol | ONE tablet FOUR times a day |

However, If I alter the dates to be

```
da.rec_date>={d '2022-01-20'}
AND da.rec_date<={d '2022-06-22'}
```

This results in 2 duplicates, correct?

Is there any way I am able to get a quantity of duplicates PER calendar fortnight?

If I extend the date ranges to a year, I'm going to get a high count of duplcates, but I would like to know how many duplicates every TWO weeks.

Is that possible in SQL?

I thought about maybe counting if the dates between two duplicate entries are within 14 days. If not then it's not a duplicate.

Otherwise I can export the data into an excel file and maybe breakdown the data using pivot tables?

Kind regards.

*EDIT*

Definition of duplicate record would be the same name, med and directions within 14 days of rec_date.

Comment: Define in details what is "duplicate records". And what is "between two dates" - does both "duplicate records" must posess in specified range or at least one of them?

Comment: Use window COUNT() function with according partitioning and window frame specifying in CTE and select the rows where this value is above 1 in outer query.

Comment: By "every two weeks" do you mean "calendar fortnight"? Or do you mean something else? Please [edit] your question to explain a bit better.

Comment: Hi Akina, would it be possible for you to show me how this would work? Thank you. I've tried the response below. But doesn't seem to work.